# Where to put XAMPP HTDOCS Confusion

Tags: ssd, xampp, io, read-write

**Is it okay to put the XAMPP Directory in your SSD?**

...considering such cases like you're a web developer and performing small writes to the files under its HTDOCS directory when you make changes / fix errors in your web dev files in it, and at the the same time...

> An SSD is flash storage. It has no moving parts. So unlike on a traditional mechanical hard drive, nothing breaks. SSD wear and tear has to do with write cycles.
>   
>  -
>   [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043634/how-to-stretch-the-life-of-your-ssd-storage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can tell you is that I have had XAMPP working directories on SSD for years without issue. I don't think XAMPP is responsible for crazy amounts of writes, so I would say you are fine.

Comment: May i ask if you dont mind. How many years have you been using your ssd where xampp is installed?

Comment: Hi Jimwel, at least four years :)

Comment: How many times reformatted?

Comment: Never. MY OS is on another physical SSD. My "long term"data on a large conventional drive, and my day to day working files, including the directories where I hold (and vhosts to) my XAMPP files are on another SSD. Never formatted. Never any problems :)